# getString() with path joining?

Tags: android, string, textview

What is the best way to reference string resources (xml) in android, using a path joining method?

**Scenario**
I have multiple string resources in xml:

```
<string name="testString1">Test 1</string>
<string name="testString2">Test 2</string>
<string name="testString3">Test 3</string>
```

In my application, I want the user to choose which string resource to return, based on their selection. However, there are going to be hundreds of options. So I'm looking for some sort of:

```
textView.setText(getString(R.string.testString + selection));
```

Any suggestions greatly welcomed,
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

From [getIdentifier](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) Android documentation.

> **getIdentifier**
>
> ```
> public int getIdentifier (String name, 
>                 String defType, 
>                 String defPackage)
> ```
>
> Return a resource identifier for the given resource name. A fully
>   qualified resource name is of the form "package:type/entry". The first
>   two components (package and type) are optional if defType and
>   defPackage, respectively, are specified here.

**Solution:** Write a method to get designed string based on given selection, such as 1, 2, 3.

```
public String getStringBasedOnSelection(int selection) {
    String name = "testString" + selection;
    int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(name, "string", getPackageName());
    return getString(resId);
}
```

**Use in code**

```
Log.i(TAG, getStringBasedOnSelection(1));
Log.i(TAG, getStringBasedOnSelection(2));
Log.i(TAG, getStringBasedOnSelection(3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Make all three one line this

```
<string name="testString">Test %d</string>
```

And usage like this

```
textView.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.project_id), selection)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to get the string resource identifier, which is always an integer, by a string.
Let's suppose you are inside an Activity class:

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(selection, "string", getPackageName());
if (id != -1)
{
    textView.setText(getString(id));
}
```

`getResources()` is a method defined in `Context` class, which returns a `Resources` object. Since I supposed you are working inside an `Activity` class, which is a subclass of `Context`, you can call `getResources()`, as well as `getString()`, without prefixing a `Context` instance.

`Resources` is a class which defines a set of methods where now are useful to you, such as `getIdentifier`. Take a look at the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources).
Be careful to check for non-existent resources. This method returns -1 if resource could not be found!!